# Sql Server multiple word search and ranking the results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Assume user enters "Vintage Audi Car" as search criteria

My table has a field "Description" as Varchar(Max)

I want to search the user entered values as Vintage OR Audi OR Car. The result should display the rows that contains all the three words in "Description" at top and rows with any two words and then rows with any one word.

Let me know how this can be achieved.

I am open to use Full Text Search.

Comment: Not being familiar with FTS, you'd really have multiple queries unioned (not `ALL`ed) together. I assume with FTS, you could write 3 queries, vintage AND audi AND car, followed by vintage AND audi + vintage AND car ... followed by vintage OR audi or car

Comment: That will decrease the performance of the query significantly. Also I cannot assume that always there will be only three words in search criteria

Answer (score 2):

That should be possible using full text search with the command CONTAINSTABLE:

```
SELECT * FROM Car 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Car, Description, 'ISABOUT (Vintage weight (.5), Audi weight (0.5), Car weight (0.5) )') AS A 
   ON Car.Id = A.[KEY] 
ORDER BY A.[RANK] DESC;
```

The rank is calculated by the weight, so a row with the description "Vintage Audi" will get a higher rank than the row with the description "Audi".

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of achieving this result using the `LIKE` operator:

```
select Description
from MyTable
where Description like '%Vintage%' OR Description like '%Audi%' OR Description like '%Car%'
order by (case when Description like '%Vintage%' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when Description like '%Audi%' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when Description like '%Car%' then 1 else 0 end) DESC
```

The `WHERE` clause limits the result to descriptions that contain at least one of the words (hence the `OR`). The `ORDER BY` adds `1` for each word from the list, bringing items with higher score to the top.

Comment: Though I have not tried this out, but I am doubtful if this query will post the records with any two words as the second priority.

Comment: Well your query was provided me the hint and probably I would be able to solve my problem. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Even i had same issue i solved it  using MYISAM engine

alter the table Car

```
ALTER TABLE  Car ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

then

```
select * FROM Car WHERE MATCH (Description) AGAINST ('Vintage Audi Car'  IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```